# how to get Query Analysis response / synonym from solrj

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am using solr synonym in my application.. here is query to from which i am getting synonym

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/analysis/field?analysis.query='+request.term+'&analysis.fieldname=description&analysis.showmatch=true&wt=json&indent=true
```

I tried same using solrj to get synonym

```
    ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
    params.set("qt", "/analysis/field");
    params.set("analysis.query", queryterm);
    params.set("analysis.fieldname", "description");
    params.set("analysis.showmatch", true);

    try {
        resp1 = server.query(params);
        System.out.println(resp1);
    } catch (SolrServerException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }

    SolrDocumentList results = resp1.getResults();
    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); ++i) {
        System.out.println(results.get(i).getFieldValue("description").toString());
    }
```

How to get synonym?

Comment: you want to find all synonyms for queryterm?

Comment: yes and also how to get that synonym in solrj...

Answer (score 1):

You can't get synonyms via SolrJ. The only way here - is to use RestAPI (Solr 4.8+)

> Synonyms For the most part, the API for managing synonyms behaves
>   similar to the API for stop words, except instead of working with a
>   list of words, we need to work with a map, where the value for each
>   entry in the map is a set of synonyms for a term. As with stop words,
>   the example server ships with a minimal set of English synonym
>   mappings that is activated by the following field type definition in
>   schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="managed_en" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>    
    <filter class="solr.ManagedSynonymFilterFactory" 
            managed="english" />    
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

To get the map of managed English synonyms, send a GET request to:

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/schema/analysis/
synonyms/english"
```

More info about that - http://lucidworks.com/blog/introducing-solrs-restmanager-and-managed-stop-words-and-synonyms/